# Odd behavior: Class type of the object retuned by the getText() method of TextView changes after creating AccessibilityNodeInfo of TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a TextView with text "Hello World!" defined in layout xml

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

TextView's getText() method returns object of Class java.lang.String

```
//Returns object of String class
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), textView.getText().getClass().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If the same is called after creating AccessibilityNodeInfo, it returns object of android.text.SpannableString

```
//Creating AccessibilityNodeInfo
AccessibilityNodeInfo info = textView.createAccessibilityNodeInfo();

//Returns object of SpannableString
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "After creating AccessibilityNodeInfo: " + textView.getText().getClass().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

How is creating AccessibilityNodeInfo relevant to the object returned by the getText() method?

**Note:** *This only happens in Android 4.3 and above*

Comment: A more important question is, why do you care?  `getText()` specifies that it returns a `CharSequence`... nothing more, nothing less.  The actual return type could be any implementation of `CharSequence`, and you should never count on it being anything else.

Comment: Well, I can not elaborate full requirements here. I can only mention that I have to deal with other developer's code and creating AccessiblityNodeInfo breaks their code. And I am just curious to know how is return type of getText() method relevant to AccessiblityNodeInfo of node?

Comment: I feel for you.  90% of my job is dealing with ultra-sucky third party code instead of doing any real work of my own.  It's considered best practice to *not* document the answers to the kind of question you're asking, so... good luck.  You may have to dive into the Android code, and even if you find your answer, you may not be able to do anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to new features like `select`, `cut`, `copy`, `paste` features added to the `AccessibilityNodeInfo`. It was introduced in Android 4.3 and is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#A11yService).

> **Select text and copy/paste**
>
> The AccessibilityNodeInfo now provides APIs that allow an
>   AccessibilityService to select, cut, copy, and paste text in a node.
>
> To specify the selection of text to cut or copy, your accessibility
>   service can use the new action, ACTION_SET_SELECTION, passing with it
>   the selection start and end position with
>   ACTION_ARGUMENT_SELECTION_START_INT and
>   ACTION_ARGUMENT_SELECTION_END_INT. Alternatively you can select text
>   by manipulating the cursor position using the existing action,
>   ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY (previously only for moving the
>   cursor position), and adding the argument
>   ACTION_ARGUMENT_EXTEND_SELECTION_BOOLEAN.
>
> You can then cut or copy with ACTION_CUT, ACTION_COPY, then later
>   paste with ACTION_PASTE.
>
> Note: These new APIs are also available for previous versions of
>   Android through the Android Support Library, with the
>   AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat class.

To implement the `select` feature, the `styleable` / `markup` objects need to be attached to the underlying text. Hence the text type is changed from `String` to `SpannableString`.

Here is the code of [View.java](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/view/View.java/?v=diff&id2=4.2.2_r1#5135) which introduced this feature. Following code changes the type to `SpannableString`.

```
@Override
public CharSequence getIterableTextForAccessibility() {
    if (!(mText instanceof Spannable)) {
        setText(mText, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
    return mText;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the source of `View` and `TextView` (at least for API level 19), it can be determined that the "culprit" is `TextView.getIterableTextForAccessibility()`. In the TextView class, it's defined as:

```
/**
 * @hide
 */
@Override
public CharSequence getIterableTextForAccessibility() {
    if (!(mText instanceof Spannable)) {
        setText(mText, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
    return mText;
}
```

This method is called as part of the `createAccessibilityNodeInfo()` sequence, in particular from `View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal()`.

Since it's not documented, it's hard to know exactly why (or even if it was intended or just a side effect), but it's clear that the text will necessarily end up being a `Spannable`, even if it wasn't one before.

From the [history of TextView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blame/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) in the GitHub mirror of the AOSP repository, it would seem that [the commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/6d17a936f73976971135aa1e6248662533343292) that introduced this logic was made by [Svetoslav Ganov](http://www.linkedin.com/in/svetoslavganov). Short of asking him, I'm not sure what else you could do to learn more. :)

As for the *"why would you need to know this"* side of the whole affair (apart from curiosity), the exact class of the TextView's text shouldn't be relevant... I assume the legacy code was doing something like `String x = (String)textView.getText()`. If you need a `String` instead of a `CharSequence`, replacing those calls by `getText().toString()` should be enough.

Comment: Bingo! The legacy code does use cast operation instead of using toString() method which lead me to this at first. I am kind of developing a library and my lib is not aware of how developers use APIs. Sigh!